# AngularJs route provider infinite loop with external website

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, route-provider

I have include ghost blog in my website at www.xxxxx.com/blog.

When I access the blog url, my application crashes as it is going into infinite loop because of route providers that I have given below.

```
.when('/',{
    templateUrl:"partials/home"
})

.when('/home',{
    templateUrl:"partials/home"
})

.when('/blog',{
    templateUrl:"/blog",    
})
```

What can be the best way to stop it going into infinite loop.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

You have a templateUrl `/blog` that is the same as the page path.

I suspect you wanted it to be `partials/blog`

Comment: No..because blog is not a partial.That is the problem.I have install ghost blog on my server which is altogether different application.Using nginx I am redirecting to www.xxxx.com/blog

Comment: Well it still makes no sense having a template url matching page path. You haven't provided enough detail on how this all fits together or why you need an angular route to point at another app

Comment: ok..My website is hosted on AWS and running on node as backend(port 3000).I also have installed ghost blog there(Port 2368).Using nginx I am redirecting it  as location /blog { proxy_pass http://localhost:2368}.So I have to accommodate this is angular route also.

Comment: none of that explains why you are trying to set up an angular route that is the same as the ghost one. Time to read [ask] and provide all pertinent details in the question

Comment: What do you suggest..How should I setup route to hit /blog?Any example

Comment: All you need is a regular link to it unless you are trying to use it somehow as a data source for your angular app.

Comment: Sorry to drag this, I might be making mistake...suppose I will give direct link as www.xxxx.com/blog and it is not part of routeprovider then  .otherwise({
  redirectTo:'/'
 }); will trigger and redirect to root.

Comment: not clear what you re expecting. if you wnt this angular to work inside ghost then you need to use their methodolgy to integrate it...otherwise you will have 2 separate apps

Comment: Hi...Thanks for help.Issue is resolved now.Issue was related to nginx configuration.Above routes are fine and working as expected.